# How to return two strings using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

How to return two parametres using AJAX?

Here is what I have. Here are 2 textareas on my html page.

```
<textarea name="source" id="source" onkeyup="myfunc(this.value);}"></textarea>
<textarea name="res1" id="res1"></textarea>
<textarea name="res2" id="res2"></textarea>
```

Onkeyup event calls **myfunc()** function from **.js file**.

**myfunc()** contains such strings:

```
...
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_file.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset= UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send("q="+encodeURIComponent(str));
```

As result, **ajax_file.php** makes some computations, calculates q and p and returns q. String q returned to textarea **res1**. Everything is OK, it works fine. But, I would like to pass the value **p** to **res2** (another textarea) as well. It's calculated, but I don't know how to pass back more than one parameter. What's the way to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the most obvious way (if you want to send two parameters) is

```
xmlhttp.send("q="+encodeURIComponent(str)+"&p="+encodeURIComponent(str1));
```

if you want to return two parameters, use an array in php and encode it in json

```
$arr = array();

$arr['str1'] = $str1;
$arr['str2'] = $str2;
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

EDIT - set also the correcxt headers before echoing the array. After doing that, parse the JSON on the client

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var resp = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML=resp.str1;
        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML=resp.str2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is still unclear for me. OK, I put $p and $q in an array $arr the way you said and made echo json_encode($arr); OK. Now, how to extract $arr['str1'] into res1? I used document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; in my .js file when I had only one returned parameter. Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec you should parse the JSON client side and then use the parameters. I edited my  answer for that. JSON is usually a Browser method, there are some javascript libraries to use in older browsers

Comment: I've put your code to the end of my question (please see above) to ask why it doesn't work. It gets an error. Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec exactly what error?Maybe you should open another question

Comment: Thank you for asking. I made a typo. My fault. Now it works. I voted for your question. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Look into JSON, which JavaScript can handle natively. This is better than any sort of string splitting, since it makes sure the output does not include character or characters that you would use for exploding the result.

Workflow is this:

- PHP writes result into an array and then encodes it with json_encode() and echos this as a response
- Javascript converts that to usable JavaScript object using array=JSON.parse(result), where result is the result from PHP.

PHP's $array['me']='you' would then be array['me'] in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could either send a delimited string "Value1,Value2,Value3" and then use the javascript split method, or use JSON: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

ajax return the whole output of the page so you can't return two strings with it but you can break that string into two

for example output of the page is : HelloWorld

now you want both Hello and World separate so make this output like : Hello,World OR Hello-World OR Hello|World

and split it with that delimiter

$("PAGE",{"var":"value"},function(response){ response.split(delimiter) })